# Hudson bAt Script and Network drives

Tags: hudson, network-drive

I build my little project with Hudson and would like to publish it on my network drive.
To do this, I wrote a little script which is executed after the build process:

```
xcopy .\Installer\bin\Release\*.* "M:\installerRelease" /I /E /Y
```

I tested it out of the working folder of hudson in the command line prompt and everything works great. After I put the code into Hudson and perform a build, Hudson says that everything works out well. So I take a look to my M drive but nothing's there. But the build log tells me that all the files were copied.

Is Hudson not able to write to the Netdrive?

Comment: I corrected mistakes for you, please use a spell checker next time so it's easier to read your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the Problem:

You need to use the server URl ...
Like:

```
//Server/installerRelease
```